# Doing a Timeout Error with Fetch - React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I have a user login function that is working. But, I want to incorporate a time out error for the fetch. Is there a way to set up a timer for 5 seconds or so that would stop trying to fetch after such a time? Otherwise, I just get a red screen after a while saying network error.

```
_userLogin() {
  var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
  if (value) {
    // if validation fails, value will be null
    if (!this.validateEmail(value.email)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      Alert.alert('Enter a valid email');
    } else {
      fetch('http://51.64.34.134:5000/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: value.email,
          password: value.password,
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          if (responseData.status == 'success') {
            this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.data.token);
            Alert.alert('Login Success!');
            this.props.navigator.push({name: 'StartScreen'});
          } else if (responseData.status == 'error') {
            Alert.alert('Login Error', responseData.message);
          }
        })
        .done();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I have made a ES6 function that wraps ES fetch into a promise, here it is:

```
export async function fetchWithTimeout(url, options, timeout = 5000) {
    return Promise.race([
        fetch(url, options),
        new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), timeout))
    ]);
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
const requestInfo = {
    method,
    headers,
    body,
};
const url = 'http://yoururl.edu.br'
let data = await fetchWithTimeout(url, requestInfo, 3000);
```

Comment: Just a quick note on this, there seems to be problems with the Android side where Promise.race is not working properly.

Comment: @MikeHuebner I am using this method in production for both android and iOS in react-native: 0.61.2. In this environment all is working fine. May you could send your scenery and your adaptation.

Comment: Sure thing, I ended up having to do something simple to just do a race condition when I'm on iOS. The Android scenario wouldn't fetch properly, instead it would just right to the fail. I couldn't figure out why as it seems promise.race works fine on both platform. Are you using Hermes by chance?

Comment: No I don't. I use the default JS engine JavaScriptCore. I have made an abstraction fetch, so all my requests pass through this method. I can assure you that I use this script for least 3 apps (ios/android in stores). For me I never got any exceptions with it. I think you have some environment issue. I am curious to know what is your exception on android.

Answer (score 9):

```js
// Wrapper function for fetch
const fetchSomething = async () => {
    let controller = new AbortController()
    setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 3000);  // abort after 3 seconds
    const resp = await fetch('some url', {signal: controller.signal});
    const json = await resp.json();
    if (!resp.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${resp.status}`);
    }
    return json;
}


// usage
try {
    let jsonResp = await fetchSomthing();
    console.log(jsonResp);
} catch (error) {
    if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
        console.log('Network Error');
    } else {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

I think using `AbortController` is the recommended way to abort a `fetch` call. The code snippet above handles the following scenarios:

1. If network is good but HTTP returns an error status, the message "HTTP error! ..." will be logged.
2. If network is down, `setTimeout` would trigger the `AbortController` to abort `fetch` after three seconds. The message "Network Error" will be logged.
3. If network is good and HTTP response is good, the response JSON will be logged.

The documentation for using `AbortController` to abort `fetch` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort).

Comment: Should we cancel the timeout after the request completed? `clearTimeout(abortTimeout);`

Comment: I didn't cancel the timeout when using the code snippet above, and it seemed to be working as expected. I suspect if fetch completes the timeout, the timeout is cancelled automatically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way of handling this as [a timeout option isn't defined in the official spec yet](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/20). [There is an abort defined](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27) which you can use in conjunction with your own timeout and Promises. For example as seen [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175#issuecomment-125779262) and [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175#issuecomment-216791333). I've copied the example code, but haven't tested it myself yet.

```
// Rough implementation. Untested.
function timeout(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      reject(new Error("timeout"))
    }, ms)
    promise.then(resolve, reject)
  })
}

timeout(1000, fetch('/hello')).then(function(response) {
  // process response
}).catch(function(error) {
  // might be a timeout error
})
```

Another option would be to modify the fetch.js module yourself to add a timeout that calls abort as seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2556#issuecomment-269570354).

Comment: By doing this way, it only solve surface of the question, it couldn't abort the request after certain time.

Comment: @TomSawyer That wasn't what was asked though; the question doesn't ask to handle aborting after a timeout. Also, my answer does include links to possible solutions for aborting in case others were looking to go that direction. So I'm not quite sure what the point of your comment was?

Comment: I pointed out for anyone who cares about how true timeout mechanism works. In the http request, one connection timeout it means aborting the connection, its allocated memory need to be release, its process need to be terminated not only return false for the ui update then keep running on the background.

Comment: If you've read one of the link you linked, the poster name `mislav` also said: `Note that this is not a connection timeout. This is a response timeout. Due to technical restrictions we can't implement a connection timeout. Also note that with the above implementation, even if the timeout happens, the original request won't be aborted because we don't have an API to abort fetch requests. Instead, the request will complete in the background but its response will get discarded.`

Comment: @TomSawyer Yes... that is literally why I wrote the first sentence in my answer, why I linked those resources, and why I said the part about abort. The answer was a summary of the choices currently available. So... I still do not understand why you are making these comments? If you think my answer is insufficient or that you can post a better one, then do so. It's the point of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to go around it:
(This is the "generic" function I use to make all calls on my app)

I created a timeout function, that will be triggered unless it is cleared before, then I clear this timeout on server response

```
const doFetch = (url, callback, data) => {
  //... creating config obj here (not relevant for this answer)
  var wasServerTimeout = false;
  var timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    wasServerTimeout = true;
    alert('Time Out');
  }, 3000);
  fetch(HOST + url, config)
    .then((response) => {
      timeout && clearTimeout(timeout); //If everything is ok, clear the timeout
      if (!wasServerTimeout) {
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      callback && callback(response.data || response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //If something goes wrong, clear the timeout
      timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
      if (!wasServerTimeout) {
        //Error logic here
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: So anyways you get it :/ but you alert if not gotten it by 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a race between 2 promises, written as a wrapper around fetch. In my case I expect the request to return json so also added that. Maybe there is a better solution, but this works correctly for me!

The wrapper returns a promise which will resolve as long as there are no code errors.
You can check the result.status for 'success' and read json data from result.data. In case of error you can read the exact error in result.data, and display it or log it somewhere. This way you always know what went wrong!

```
var yourFetchWrapperFunction = function (
  method,
  url,
  headers,
  body,
  timeout = 5000,
) {
  var timeoutPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout, {
      status: 'error',
      code: 666,
      data:
        'Verbinding met de cloud kon niet tot stand gebracht worden: Timeout.',
    });
  });
  return Promise.race([
    timeoutPromise,
    fetch(connectionType + '://' + url, {
      method: method,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    }),
  ])
    .then(
      (result) => {
        var Status = result.status;
        return result
          .json()
          .then(
            function (data) {
              if (Status === 200 || Status === 0) {
                return {status: 'success', code: Status, data: data};
              } else {
                return {
                  status: 'error',
                  code: Status,
                  data: 'Error (' + data.status_code + '): ' + data.message,
                };
              }
            },
            function (response) {
              return {
                status: 'error',
                code: Status,
                data: 'json promise failed' + response,
              };
            },
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            return {status: 'error', code: 666, data: 'no json response'};
          });
      },
      function (error) {
        return {status: 'error', code: 666, data: 'connection timed out'};
      },
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      return {status: 'error', code: 666, data: 'connection timed out'};
    });
};
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but the fetch won't be cancelled, which is a problem if you're uploading data for example

Comment: Yes indeed, but slow connections are always a p*** in the a**! I try to minimize the upload data size by splitting and rejoining on the server, and stopping uploads when one part fails. Later you can try again with the remaining file parts... this helped me solving issues with bad wifi/4g connections.

Answer (score 1):

```
  let controller = new AbortController()
      
      setTimeout( () => {
          controller.abort()
      }, 10000);    // 10,000 means 10 seconds

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',        
        headers: headers, 
        body: JSON.stringify(param),
        signal: controller.signal
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 60,000 means 1 minutes

Answer (score 0):

> I may be late but i made a code which is 100% working to timeout an API request using fetch.

```
fetch_timeout(url, options) {
  let timeout = 1000;
  let timeout_err = {
    ok: false,
    status: 408,
  };
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(resolve, reject)
      .catch(() => {
        alert('timeout.');
      });
    setTimeout(reject.bind(null, timeout_err), timeout);
  });
}
```

You just need to pass the `api-endpoint` to the url and `body` to the `options` parameter.